# How to create a mathematical expression from operators and operands in a queue

Tags: c++, mathematical-expressions

I'm trying to build a mathematical expression (including parenthesis) with the operators and operands included in a queue.

Here is my code:

```
string createExp (queue<char> q) {
    string s;
    string s1, s2;
    char c;

    while (!q.empty()) {

        c = q.front();

        if (c == 'x') {
            s += "x";
            q.pop();
        }

        else if (c == 'y') {
            s += "y";
            q.pop();
        }

        else if (c == 'a') {
            s += "avg(";
            q.pop();

            s1 = createExp(q);
            q.pop();
            s2 = createExp(q);
            q.pop();
            s += s1;
            s += ',';
            s += s2;
            s += ')';
        }

        else if (c == 's') {
            s += "sin(pi*";
            q.pop();
            op++;
        }
        else if (c == 'c') {
            s += "cos(pi*";
            q.pop();
            op++;
        }
        else {
            s += "*";
            q.pop();
        }
    }

    while (op > cp) {
        s += ")";
        cp++;
    }

    return (s);
}
```

As you can see, in the case of the average (avg), I'm trying to call recursively to the function to obtain the next sequence of values.

For example, if my queue contains the next values:

> s m a y x y

The expression should be like this:

> sin(pi*(avg(y,x)*y)

But my code return this sequence:

> sin(pi**avg(yyx)yyxyyx

Could you help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried to debug step by step?

Comment: Or at least with shorter/simpler inputs?

Comment: Where are your `op` and `cp` defined? Are they global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final recursive solution:

```
int cp = 0,  op = 0;

string recursiveExp (queue<char>& q) {
    char e;

    if (!q.empty()) {
        e = q.front();
        if (e == 'x' || e == 'y') {
            q.pop();
            s += e;
        }

        else if (e == 's') {
            q.pop();
            s += "sin(pi*";
            op++;
            recursiveExp(q);
            s += ")";
            cp++;
        }

       else if (e == 'c') {
            q.pop();
            s += "cos(pi*";
            op++;
            recursiveExp(q);
            s += ")";
            cp++;
        }

        else if (e == 'a') {
            q.pop();
            s += "avg(";
            op++;
            recursiveExp(q);
            s += ",";
            recursiveExp(q);
            s += ")";
            cp++;
        }

        else if (e == 'm'){
            q.pop();
            s += "(";
            op++;
            recursiveExp(q);
            s += "*";
            recursiveExp(q);
            s += ")";
            cp++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

This part of processing `avg(-,-)` is horribly broken:

```
s1 = createExp(q);
q.pop();
s2 = createExp(q);
q.pop();
```

You're passing the queue by value, which creates a copy of it.  Then you can't find out how many times the recursion popped the queue.  But you magically assume that you should remove exactly one element.  What if one of the arguments had a function call or operator in it.

To make matters worse, the recursion processes the entire rest of the queue, not just one expression.

Comment: So, in your opinion, which would be the best way to solve this problems? Maybe use recursion in all the function?

Comment: Yes, recursion, no loop, and I would pass the queue by reference so that the recursive calls control how many operands get removed.

Comment: And how could be this function?

Answer (score 1):

The `**` comes from both `m` in the string and you explicitly writing `sin(pi*` in the code.

In addition, the recursion into avg (when creating `s1` seems to index the entire expression so you are getting `yyx`). You must make sure it only reads 1 complete expression out of the stack, not the rest of the thing. This is tricky because you need to tell the difference between `avg(x,y)` and `avg(x+y,y*x)` for example.

Comment: It comes from `m` putting the `*` into the output string immediately, instead of parsing two operands and putting `*` between them.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, didn't i write the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a small modification of your code and it works perfectly:

```
int cp = 0,  op = 0;

std::string createExp(std::queue< char >& q)
{
    std::string s;
    std::string s1, s2;
    char c;

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        c = q.front();

        if (c == 'x')
        {
            s += "x";
            q.pop();
        }
        else if (c == 'y')
        {
            s += "y";
            q.pop();
        }
        else if (c == 'a')
        {
            s += "avg(";
            q.pop();

            s1 = q.front(); // here
            q.pop();
            s2 = q.front(); // and here
            q.pop();
            s += s1;
            s += ',';
            s += s2;
            s += ')*';
        }
        else if (c == 's')
        {
            s += "sin(pi*";
            q.pop();
            op++;
        }
        else if (c == 'c')
        {
            s += "cos(pi*";
            q.pop();
            op++;
        }
        else
        {
//             s += "*";
            q.pop();
        }
    }

    while (op > cp)
    {
        s += ")";
        cp++;
    }

    return (s);
}
```

But this will work only if your operator is always `*`. If you need also the other operators, then you need a more complex thing.